# How to sleep only after executing a command?

Tags: java, android

I have a `DialogFragment`, with a public interface and a method to save the callback:

```
public class ChooseExportTypeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
    public interface ExportTypeClickListener{
        public void doPositiveClick(ExportTypeEnum exportType);
    }

    public void setOnConfirmClickListener( ExportTypeClickListener callback ){
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    //...
}
```

I declare a `DialogFragment` like this:

```
final ChooseExportTypeDialogFragment chooseExportTypeDialogFragment = new ChooseExportTypeDialogFragment();
chooseExportTypeDialogFragment.setOnConfirmClickListener( new ExportTypeClickListener() {

@Override
public void doPositiveClick( ExportTypeEnum exportType ) {
    toast.setText("Preparing Export...");
    toast.show();
    controller.onExport( adapter.getSelected() , exportType);
    chooseExportTypeDialogFragment.dismiss();
}
} );
chooseExportTypeDialogFragment.show( controller.getSupportFragmentManager(), "notification" );
```

In the method `onExport()`, I perform a `Thread.sleep(3000)` (among other things).

It seems that when `doPositiveClick()` is invoked, the sleeping (which is in `onExport()`) occurs **before** `toast.show()`. I tried to put both operations (`toast.show()` and `.onExport()`) in `synchronized` blocks, hoping the `sleep` will start only after finishing `toast.show()`, but the same problem happens.

I also tried putting `toast.show()` in a thread, then `.start()` it and `.join()` it. And only then call `onExport()`. Same problem

How can I show the `toast` and only then let `onExport()` start?

Comment: Oh god, never do Thread.sleep() on the main thread. That will literally stop the entire application and freeze it for 3 seconds.
If you wish to wait 3 seconds with dismissing the dialog, then use a Handler and .postDelayed(), much much cleaner and it doesn't freeze the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread.sleep is rather problematic in Android espessially when performed in the UI thread because it can cause other elements (in your case Toast) to stop responding. An alternative to your problem is to execute your controller.onExport() logic inside a handler.

```
@Override
public void doPositiveClick( ExportTypeEnum exportType ){
        toast.setText("Preparing Export...");
        toast.show();

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                controller.onExport( adapter.getSelected() , exportType);
            }
            }, 3500);

        chooseExportTypeDialogFragment.dismiss();
}
```

You might also need to disable clickability of  your Dialog buttons while waiting for the toast text to finish.

Comment: My goal is not executing `onExport()` only after the toast finishes. I just want to show the toast, then immediately start `onExport()`. Inside `onExport()`, I execute some shell command, and I need some kind of sleep after it, then continue with the other stuff in `onExport()`

Comment: If that's the case then why not move the handler inside your onExport to the specific actions that need to 'wait'?

Comment: Will try that. Thanks

Comment: contrary to popular belief, `LENGTH_LONG` is not a number of seconds, it is only a flag. There is no way that I know of to know the actual duration of a toast.

Comment: OK I chose this answer as a method, though this is not the exact solution. The answer is just like everybody is saying: don't use `Thread.sleep()`. Use a `Handler` instead.

Comment: This answer follows your question "How can I show the toast and only then let onExport() start?". Since you changed the requirements in a comment and havent edited the official post I answered in a comment as well in order to not confuse future readers!